# About Directory Contents in asp.net

Tags: c#-4.0

I have a directory and I want to save a image in that directory.

How would I know an image already exists in that directory or not?

Answer (score 1):

You can determine if *the* file exists (by name) using the [`File.Exists`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.exists.aspx) method. There is, however, the possibility of *a* file being saved with the same name between the time of checking and saving your own.

In a web application I often used mapped [GUID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Globally_unique_identifier) values as file names.

Anyway, *I think* this is what you're asking, though it isn't greatly conveyed as to your exact current predicament.